# Is $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ complete with the norm $\|u\|_\Delta:=(\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2)^{1/2}?$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Is it true that $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ is complete with the norm $$\|u\|_\Delta:=(\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2)^{1/2}?$$ Above $\Delta:C^\infty_0(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)\longrightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ is the Laplacian operator defined by $\displaystyle \Delta=-\sum_{j=1}^n D_j^2$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because already for $n=1$ we have that the Sobolev space $H_0^2$ is a subset of your space.